# Accented letters, Unicode and LaTeX accents

Tags: unicode, accents, unicode-math

So, there are three kinds of entities:

1. accented Latin letters
2. Unicode code points representing them
3. Standard TeX/LaTeX commands that represent them.

Of these, Unicode code points are defined best. Everything is in the standard. The two others are more loose:

Which are the Latin letters? Is `Mc` a letter? How about `ae`? What is considered an accent? There are so many of them.

Which are the "standard" latex/tex commands? Which packages are allowed, and which are not?

There is no definite one answer to these questions. But, I presume there must be tables which carry out some kind of unification of these terms. 
This question asks for a more or less "standard" or "community acceptable" table of mappings between instances of these three concepts. If this sounds to philosophical, then read this question as "Standard table of mapping of Unicode and LaTeX accents". One way of searching would be in the `unicode-math` package, but there must be more concise maps, presumably used by other the designers of `unicode-math`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that rather than look at `unicode-math` it's more natural to look at `inputenc`'s utf8 support (if your main interest is textual accented characters rather than math symbols). That maps Unicode input to classic latex markup.

The base latex distribution has a file `utf8enc.dfu` that contains the mapping as far as it is implemented. As memory constraints are a lot less of a problem now than they were initially gradually more Unicode characters have been added, and quite a lot more are added in the next release due in a day or so, the current development version is

```
%%
%% This is file `utf8enc.dfu',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% utf8ienc.dtx  (with options: `all')
%% 
%% This is a generated file.
%% 
%% The source is maintained by the LaTeX Project team and bug
%% reports for it can be opened at http://latex-project.org/bugs.html
%% (but please observe conditions on bug reports sent to that address!)
%% 
%% 
%% Copyright 1993-2016
%% The LaTeX3 Project and any individual authors listed elsewhere
%% in this file.
%% 
%% This file was generated from file(s) of the LaTeX base system.
%% --------------------------------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3c
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This file has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%% 
%% This file may only be distributed together with a copy of the LaTeX
%% base system. You may however distribute the LaTeX base system without
%% such generated files.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the LaTeX base distribution is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'. See also `legal.txt' for additional
%% information.
%% 
%% The list of derived (unpacked) files belonging to the distribution
%% and covered by LPPL is defined by the unpacking scripts (with
%% extension .ins) which are part of the distribution.
 \ProvidesFile{utf8enc.dfu}
   [2015/12/03 v1.1r UTF-8 support for inputenc]
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A1}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A2}{\textcent}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A3}{\textsterling}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A4}{\textcurrency}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A5}{\textyen}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A6}{\textbrokenbar}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A7}{\textsection}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A8}{\textasciidieresis}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A9}{\textcopyright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AA}{\textordfeminine}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AB}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AC}{\textlnot}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AD}{\-}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AE}{\textregistered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AF}{\textasciimacron}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\textdegree}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B1}{\textpm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\texttwosuperior}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B3}{\textthreesuperior}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B4}{\textasciiacute}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B5}{\textmu} % micro sign
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B6}{\textparagraph}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B7}{\textperiodcentered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B8}{\c\ }
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B9}{\textonesuperior}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BA}{\textordmasculine}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BB}{\guillemotright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BC}{\textonequarter}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BD}{\textonehalf}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BE}{\textthreequarters}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00BF}{\textquestiondown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C0}{\@tabacckludge`A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C1}{\@tabacckludge'A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C2}{\^A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C3}{\~A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C4}{\"A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C5}{\r A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C6}{\AE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C7}{\c C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C8}{\@tabacckludge`E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00C9}{\@tabacckludge'E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CA}{\^E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CB}{\"E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CC}{\@tabacckludge`I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CD}{\@tabacckludge'I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CE}{\^I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00CF}{\"I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D0}{\DH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D1}{\~N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D2}{\@tabacckludge`O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D3}{\@tabacckludge'O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D4}{\^O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D5}{\~O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D6}{\"O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{\texttimes}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D8}{\O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D9}{\@tabacckludge`U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DA}{\@tabacckludge'U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DB}{\^U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DC}{\"U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DD}{\@tabacckludge'Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DE}{\TH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00DF}{\ss}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E0}{\@tabacckludge`a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E1}{\@tabacckludge'a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E2}{\^a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E3}{\~a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E4}{\"a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E5}{\r a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E6}{\ae}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E7}{\c c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E8}{\@tabacckludge`e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00E9}{\@tabacckludge'e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EA}{\^e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EB}{\"e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EC}{\@tabacckludge`\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00ED}{\@tabacckludge'\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EE}{\^\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00EF}{\"\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F0}{\dh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F1}{\~n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F2}{\@tabacckludge`o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F3}{\@tabacckludge'o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F4}{\^o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F5}{\~o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F6}{\"o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F7}{\textdiv}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F8}{\o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00F9}{\@tabacckludge`u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FA}{\@tabacckludge'u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FB}{\^u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FC}{\"u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FD}{\@tabacckludge'y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FE}{\th}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FF}{\"y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0100}{\@tabacckludge=A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0101}{\@tabacckludge=a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0102}{\u A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0103}{\u a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0104}{\k A}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0105}{\k a}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0106}{\@tabacckludge'C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0107}{\@tabacckludge'c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0108}{\^C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0109}{\^c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010A}{\.C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010B}{\.c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010C}{\v C}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010D}{\v c}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010E}{\v D}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{010F}{\v d}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0110}{\DJ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0111}{\dj}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0112}{\@tabacckludge=E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0113}{\@tabacckludge=e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0114}{\u E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0115}{\u e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0116}{\.E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0117}{\.e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0118}{\k E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0119}{\k e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011A}{\v E}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011B}{\v e}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011C}{\^G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011D}{\^g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011E}{\u G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{011F}{\u g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0120}{\.G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0121}{\.g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0122}{\c G}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0123}{\c g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0124}{\^H}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0125}{\^h}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0128}{\~I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0129}{\~\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012A}{\@tabacckludge=I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012B}{\@tabacckludge=\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012C}{\u I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012D}{\u\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012E}{\k I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{012F}{\k\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0130}{\.I}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0131}{\i}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0132}{\IJ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0133}{\ij}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0134}{\^J}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0135}{\^\j}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0136}{\c K}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0137}{\c k}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0139}{\@tabacckludge'L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013A}{\@tabacckludge'l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013B}{\c L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013C}{\c l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013D}{\v L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{013E}{\v l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0141}{\L}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0142}{\l}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0143}{\@tabacckludge'N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0144}{\@tabacckludge'n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0145}{\c N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0146}{\c n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0147}{\v N}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0148}{\v n}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014A}{\NG}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014B}{\ng}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014C}{\@tabacckludge=O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014D}{\@tabacckludge=o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014E}{\u O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{014F}{\u o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0150}{\H O}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0151}{\H o}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0152}{\OE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0153}{\oe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0154}{\@tabacckludge'R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0155}{\@tabacckludge'r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0156}{\c R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0157}{\c r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0158}{\v R}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0159}{\v r}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015A}{\@tabacckludge'S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015B}{\@tabacckludge's}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015C}{\^S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015D}{\^s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015E}{\c S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{015F}{\c s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0160}{\v S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0161}{\v s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0162}{\c T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0163}{\c t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0164}{\v T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0165}{\v t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0168}{\~U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0169}{\~u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016A}{\@tabacckludge=U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016B}{\@tabacckludge=u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016C}{\u U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016D}{\u u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016E}{\r U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{016F}{\r u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0170}{\H U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0171}{\H u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0172}{\k U}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0173}{\k u}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0174}{\^W}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0175}{\^w}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0176}{\^Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0177}{\^y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0178}{\"Y}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0179}{\@tabacckludge'Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017A}{\@tabacckludge'z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017B}{\.Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017C}{\.z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017D}{\v Z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{017E}{\v z}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0192}{\textflorin}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01F5}{\@tabacckludge'g}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0218}{\textcommabelow S}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0219}{\textcommabelow s}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021A}{\textcommabelow T}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{021B}{\textcommabelow t}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02C6}{\textasciicircum}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02C7}{\textasciicaron}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02DC}{\textasciitilde}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02D8}{\textasciibreve}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{02DD}{\textacutedbl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0400}{\@tabacckludge`\CYRE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0401}{\CYRYO}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0402}{\CYRDJE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0403}{\@tabacckludge'\CYRG}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0404}{\CYRIE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0405}{\CYRDZE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0406}{\CYRII}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0407}{\CYRYI}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0408}{\CYRJE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0409}{\CYRLJE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040A}{\CYRNJE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040B}{\CYRTSHE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040C}{\@tabacckludge'\CYRK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040D}{\@tabacckludge`\CYRI}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040E}{\CYRUSHRT}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{040F}{\CYRDZHE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0410}{\CYRA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0411}{\CYRB}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0412}{\CYRV}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0413}{\CYRG}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0414}{\CYRD}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0415}{\CYRE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0416}{\CYRZH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0417}{\CYRZ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0418}{\CYRI}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0419}{\CYRISHRT}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041A}{\CYRK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041B}{\CYRL}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041C}{\CYRM}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041D}{\CYRN}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041E}{\CYRO}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{041F}{\CYRP}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0420}{\CYRR}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0421}{\CYRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0422}{\CYRT}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0423}{\CYRU}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0424}{\CYRF}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0425}{\CYRH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0426}{\CYRC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0427}{\CYRCH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0428}{\CYRSH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0429}{\CYRSHCH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042A}{\CYRHRDSN}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042B}{\CYRERY}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042C}{\CYRSFTSN}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042D}{\CYREREV}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042E}{\CYRYU}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{042F}{\CYRYA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0430}{\cyra}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0431}{\cyrb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0432}{\cyrv}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0433}{\cyrg}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0434}{\cyrd}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0435}{\cyre}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0436}{\cyrzh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0437}{\cyrz}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0438}{\cyri}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0439}{\cyrishrt}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043A}{\cyrk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043B}{\cyrl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043C}{\cyrm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043D}{\cyrn}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043E}{\cyro}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{043F}{\cyrp}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0440}{\cyrr}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0441}{\cyrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0442}{\cyrt}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0443}{\cyru}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0444}{\cyrf}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0445}{\cyrh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0446}{\cyrc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0447}{\cyrch}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0448}{\cyrsh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0449}{\cyrshch}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044A}{\cyrhrdsn}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044B}{\cyrery}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044C}{\cyrsftsn}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044D}{\cyrerev}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044E}{\cyryu}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044F}{\cyrya}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0450}{\@tabacckludge`\cyre}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0451}{\cyryo}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0452}{\cyrdje}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0453}{\@tabacckludge'\cyrg}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0454}{\cyrie}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0455}{\cyrdze}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0456}{\cyrii}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0457}{\cyryi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0458}{\cyrje}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0459}{\cyrlje}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045A}{\cyrnje}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045B}{\cyrtshe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045C}{\@tabacckludge'\cyrk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045D}{\@tabacckludge`\cyri}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045E}{\cyrushrt}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{045F}{\cyrdzhe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0462}{\CYRYAT}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0463}{\cyryat}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{046A}{\CYRBYUS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{046B}{\cyrbyus}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0472}{\CYRFITA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0473}{\cyrfita}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0474}{\CYRIZH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0475}{\cyrizh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0476}{\C\CYRIZH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0477}{\C\cyrizh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{048C}{\CYRSEMISFTSN}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{048D}{\cyrsemisftsn}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{048E}{\CYRRTICK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{048F}{\cyrrtick}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0490}{\CYRGUP}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0491}{\cyrgup}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0492}{\CYRGHCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0493}{\cyrghcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0494}{\CYRGHK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0495}{\cyrghk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0496}{\CYRZHDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0497}{\cyrzhdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0498}{\CYRZDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0499}{\cyrzdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049A}{\CYRKDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049B}{\cyrkdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049C}{\CYRKVCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049D}{\cyrkvcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049E}{\CYRKHCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{049F}{\cyrkhcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A0}{\CYRKBEAK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A1}{\cyrkbeak}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A2}{\CYRNDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A3}{\cyrndsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A4}{\CYRNG}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A5}{\cyrng}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A6}{\CYRPHK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A7}{\cyrphk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A8}{\CYRABHHA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04A9}{\cyrabhha}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AA}{\CYRSDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AB}{\cyrsdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AC}{\CYRTDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AD}{\cyrtdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AE}{\CYRY}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04AF}{\cyry}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B0}{\CYRYHCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B1}{\cyryhcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B2}{\CYRHDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B3}{\cyrhdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B4}{\CYRTETSE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B5}{\cyrtetse}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B6}{\CYRCHRDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B7}{\cyrchrdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B8}{\CYRCHVCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04B9}{\cyrchvcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BA}{\CYRSHHA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BB}{\cyrshha}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BC}{\CYRABHCH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BD}{\cyrabhch}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BE}{\CYRABHCHDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04BF}{\cyrabhchdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C0}{\CYRpalochka}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C1}{\U\CYRZH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C2}{\U\cyrzh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C3}{\CYRKHK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C4}{\cyrkhk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C5}{\CYRLDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C6}{\cyrldsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C7}{\CYRNHK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04C8}{\cyrnhk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04CB}{\CYRCHLDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04CC}{\cyrchldsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04CD}{\CYRMDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04CE}{\cyrmdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D0}{\U\CYRA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D1}{\U\cyra}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D2}{\"\CYRA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D3}{\"\cyra}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D4}{\CYRAE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D5}{\cyrae}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D6}{\U\CYRE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D7}{\U\cyre}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D8}{\CYRSCHWA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04D9}{\cyrschwa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DA}{\"\CYRSCHWA}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DB}{\"\cyrschwa}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DC}{\"\CYRZH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DD}{\"\cyrzh}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DE}{\"\CYRZ}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04DF}{\"\cyrz}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E0}{\CYRABHDZE}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E1}{\cyrabhdze}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E2}{\@tabacckludge=\CYRI}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E3}{\@tabacckludge=\cyri}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E4}{\"\CYRI}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E5}{\"\cyri}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E6}{\"\CYRO}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E7}{\"\cyro}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E8}{\CYROTLD}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04E9}{\cyrotld}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04EC}{\"\CYREREV}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04ED}{\"\cyrerev}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04EE}{\@tabacckludge=\CYRU}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04EF}{\@tabacckludge=\cyru}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F0}{\"\CYRU}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F1}{\"\cyru}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F2}{\H\CYRU}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F3}{\H\cyru}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F4}{\"\CYRCH}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F5}{\"\cyrch}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F6}{\CYRGDSC}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F7}{\cyrgdsc}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F8}{\"\CYRERY}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04F9}{\"\cyrery}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FA}{\CYRGDSCHCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FB}{\cyrgdschcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FC}{\CYRHHK}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FD}{\cyrhhk}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FE}{\CYRHHCRS}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{04FF}{\cyrhhcrs}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0E3F}{\textbaht}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E02}{\.B}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{01E03}{\.b}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200C}{\textcompwordmark}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2013}{\textendash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2014}{\textemdash}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2016}{\textbardbl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2018}{\textquoteleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2019}{\textquoteright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201A}{\quotesinglbase}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201C}{\textquotedblleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201D}{\textquotedblright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201E}{\quotedblbase}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2020}{\textdagger}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2021}{\textdaggerdbl}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2022}{\textbullet}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{\textellipsis}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2030}{\textperthousand}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2031}{\textpertenthousand}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2039}{\guilsinglleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{203A}{\guilsinglright}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{203B}{\textreferencemark}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{203D}{\textinterrobang}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2044}{\textfractionsolidus}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{204E}{\textasteriskcentered}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2052}{\textdiscount}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20A1}{\textcolonmonetary}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20A4}{\textlira}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20A6}{\textnaira}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20A9}{\textwon}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AB}{\textdong}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20AC}{\texteuro}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{20B1}{\textpeso}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2103}{\textcelsius}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2116}{\textnumero}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2117}{\textcircledP}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211E}{\textrecipe}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2120}{\textservicemark}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2122}{\texttrademark}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2126}{\textohm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2127}{\textmho}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{212E}{\textestimated}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2190}{\textleftarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2191}{\textuparrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2192}{\textrightarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2193}{\textdownarrow}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2329}{\textlangle}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{232A}{\textrangle}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2422}{\textblank}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2423}{\textvisiblespace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{25E6}{\textopenbullet}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{25EF}{\textbigcircle}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{266A}{\textmusicalnote}

\endinput
%%
%% End of file `utf8enc.dfu'.
```

Which tells you that for example  `\^{u}` is Unicode U+00FB